# How to make Django send POST request not GET

Tags: django, post, django-forms, get

I don't know why my HTML file sends a GET instead of POST. This is the output:

```
[02/Mar/2020 16:01:11] "GET /about/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5541
```

This is the HTML post method:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Contacto{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if 'ok' in request.GET %}
        <p><b>Su mensaje se ha enviado correctamente, en breve nos pondremos en contacto con usted.</b></p>
    {% endif %}
<h1>Contactanos</h1>
<p class="lead">Envianos tu correo o tus comentarios al siguiente formulario</p>
<body>
 <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nombre *</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        {{form.name}}
                    </div>
                    {{form.name.errors}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email *</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        {{form.email}}
                    </div>
                    {{form.email.errors}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mensaje *</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        {{form.content}}
                    </div>
                    {{form.content.errors}}
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                        <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block py-2" value="Enviar"> -->
                        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
                </div>
            </form>
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: With the given information we can not solve your problem. How do you let the browser make the request? It look a bit odd to make a POST request to the `/about` page anyway.

Comment: the about.html page got the form page. when I send a request the browser show me in the url section: http://192.168.0.21:8000/about/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=GLFXJfWkIxHxXYJ98cKPK

Comment: are you sure you are observing a GET request AFTER you submit the form and not confusing the GET request when actually browsing to the about page?

Comment: when you first time render the page it can GET request after that when you submit form then it must be post request. Try this.

Comment: And also in your view check request type. And also share your views.py file.

Comment: I resolved my problem recreating the html5 file, maybe there was a missing letter or code before, so now my request send POST form.